# Error I get when using selenium with Python

Tags: amazon-ses

I have a voice assistant project I'm trying to do with Python. But there are errors I get and I am looking for a solution

Code:
import random
import time
from playsound import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import pyaudio
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

class VoiceAssistant():
def **init**(self):
self.firefox_driver_path = "C:\Users\hyperdesign\Desktop\geckodriver.exe"  # Specify the path where Geckodriver is downloaded
self.r = sr.Recognizer()

```
# Text-to-speech section
def speak(self, text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    audio_file = "audio" + str(random.randint(0, 123465456414116)) + ".mp3"
    tts.save(audio_file)
    playsound(audio_file)
    os.remove(audio_file)

# Voice recording section
def record_voice(self):
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening....")
        audio = self.r.listen(source)
        voice = " "
        try:
            voice = self.r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.speak("I couldn't understand what you said. Please repeat.")

        return voice
    
# Respond to the spoken words
def respond_to_voice(self, spoken_text):
    if "hello" in spoken_text:
        self.speak("Hello to you too")
    elif "hi" in spoken_text:
        self.speak("Hi there!")

    # Open YouTube videos
    elif "open video" in spoken_text or "play music" in spoken_text or "open YouTube" in spoken_text:
        self.speak("What should I open?")
        data = self.record_voice()
        self.speak("Opening {}...".format(data))
        time.sleep(1)
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(data)
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.firefox_driver_path)
        browser.get(url)

    # Search on Google
    elif "open Google" in spoken_text or "search" in spoken_text:
        self.speak("What should I search for?")
        data = self.record_voice()
        self.speak("Here are the results for {}.".format(data))
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}".format(data)
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.firefox_driver_path)
        browser.get(url)

    # Weather forecast
    elif "weather forecast" in spoken_text or "weather" in spoken_text:
        response = self.record_voice()
        # Additional weather forecast actions can be added here.
```

assistant = VoiceAssistant()

while True:
voice_input = assistant.record_voice()

```
if voice_input != " ":
    voice_input = voice_input.lower()
    print("Voice Input:", voice_input)
    assistant.respond_to_voice(voice_input)
```

When I say "Open music", I can play the music I want, but I get an error when I open it, I get the following error :Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\hyperdesign\Desktop\Voice assistant\voice assistant.py", line 77, in 
assistant.ses_karsilik(ses)
File "c:\Users\hyperdesign\Desktop\Voice Assistant\sesliasistan\sesliasistan.py", line 52, in ses_karsilik
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.firefox_driver_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
PS C:\Users\hyperdesign>